# IFrame Wmode Interrupts Fixed Menu

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, wmode

I have a youtube video that is embedded, but the menu that has a fixed position is not scrolling over it; rather, the video is overlaying the menu upon scrolling.

The following snippet of code shows what I have currently tried.

```
<iframe id="lesson_demo" style="position: relative; top: 115px; left:430px; " width="450" height="280" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ae_DKNwK_ms&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>

&wmode=transparent
?wmode=transparent
&wmode=opaque
?wmode=opaque
```

None of these variations have worked.  Please let me know if you've found a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

change your link to this

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/ae_DKNwK_ms?wmode=transparent`

that is all you need.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/buhvf/30/)

Edit:
Remove the `position: relative` from the `<iframe>` for it to work.

Comment: For whatever reason this works on Chrome and IE, but not Firefox.

Comment: I made this in firefox 19 and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/buhvf/30/ if you still need help let me know